# iOS - Time taken to save an array to disk

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, save

I am using the following code to save an NSMutableArray to disk:

```
[myArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Assuming an array of roughly 400 objects, can anyone tell me if saving via this method is a time-consuming process? At the moment there is potential for the file to be saved multiple times in rather quick succession (something I am trying to fix), but I was wondering if this could cause a problem at some stage if the array gets much bigger?

Kind regards

Comment: what kinds of problems are you expecting ?

Comment: Well, to exaggerate in the extreme, if saving were to take 20 seconds and a method tries to save to a file and then another method tries to save to the same file before that '20 seconds' is up, would it result in data corruption?

Comment: Just consider that disk I/O is costly. If your data is changing in quick succession try to manage it in memory itself.Write when it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, iPod Touch 4 flash write speed is ≈ 18 MB/s (I've used code from [this](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations-leopard-edition.html) article for measurements).

You may see what is the size of saved file on the device by going to Xcode Organizer → Devices tab → In your device select Applications → Your application → Select file and press Download.

For simulator, go to `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<iOS version>/Applications/<App ID>/Documents`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things here -

1. Try to limit the number of I/O transactions as a rule in general.
2. If you can try limit I/O by having some kind of in-memory cache & flush the cache to disk only when required.
3. Next for I/O task at hand for you; have only one thread writing & reading your file. If you cant ensure this then you need to implement some sort of file locking mechanisms etc. All this can get ugly. Its better you just have one thread doing both writing & reading. This way the tasks are serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing e.g. at every update of the array, why not keep the changes in memory and just flush them to disk at applicationDidMoveToBackground or other application event that ensures it being written before the application is killed?